# Replacing an xml tag with regex

Tags: python, regex

I usually use lxml to parse xml, but in this case, I just need to change the content of a single tag.

```
<sales_start_date>YYYY-MM-DD</sales_start_date>
```

YYYY-MM-DD is a variable date.

How would I replace the above to:

```
<sales_start_date>2013-01-01</sales_start_date>
```

Here is what I currently have (which sort of works)

```
re.sub('<sales_start_date>[\d-]+</sales_start_date>', 
       '<sales_start_date>2013-01-01</sales_start_date>', 
        data)
```

Comment: And what's wrong with using `lmxl` to replace the content - and what's "(which sort of works)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the exact tags, this is pretty simple, just grab any character until the next tag (any character not `<`):

```
re.sub('<sales_start_date>[^<]+</sales_start_date>', 
       '<sales_start_date>2013-01-01</sales_start_date>', 
        data)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
re.sub('<sales_start_date>.+</sales_start_date>', 
       '<sales_start_date>2013-01-01</sales_start_date>', 
        data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more specific regex, such as:

```
r'<sales_start_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}</sales_start_date>'
```

Answer (score -1):

[\d-]+ is not going to match YYYY-MM-DD but only YYYY-MM-

try [\d-]+\d or \d+-\d+-\d+

Comment: `\d+-\d+-\d+` ? or just `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` is probably better